# Tomcat 7 acccepts incomplete data - expecting SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, tomcat, post

I have a tomcat based java web application. 
The problem i discovered with tomcat 7 accepts incomplete data.

My scenario:
I tried to send a HTTP POST request with a ~100kb JSON body.
I stop the client in middle of request.

Expected behavior:
    I expect the request to be invalidated, error code as response.
Actual behavior:
   Application receive partial JSON.

I can reproduce every time.

When i read the request object:
 - Content-Length header is correct .
 - JSON in body is partial.

I reproduced with following tomcat versions:
  7.0.57
  7.0.63 
I could not reproduce with tomcat 8.0.24.
For me upgrade it is not possible.

It is possible to configure tomcat to reject partial requests?
I would not implement validations for problems where tomcat should take care.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry, the description was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you search for the [FailedRequestFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Failed_Request_Filter).

Add the following code to your web.xml to add the filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FailedRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.FailedRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: I so not see how FailedRequestFilter can validate integrity of HTTP body.  I have incomplete json in body.